# XPath testing attributes of different paths against eachother

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have these XML files:

include_paths.xml

```
<includes>
    <include name="foo" path="path/to/foo">
    <include name="bar" path="path/to/bar">
</includes>
```

main.xml

```
<model>
    <include file="foo">
    <include file="bar">
</model>
```

XSLT stylesheet (sheet.xslt)

```
<xsl:param name="include_paths"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//include"/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="include">
  <li><a href="#{document($include_paths)/includes/include[@name = @file]/@name}"><xsl:value-of select="@file"/></a></li>
</xsl:template>
```

I run the transformation with

`xsltproc --stringparam include_paths include_paths.xml sheet.xslt main.xml`

What this code is supposed to do is that I first give the script a parameter containing the file path of `include_paths.xml` which defines some include paths. This parameter is declared globally and used in the "include" template. When iterating through the includes from `main.xml`, I want to put in an `<a>` tag linking to the path for which the name matches in the include tags from the different XML files.

So for example, I want the `<li>` item that ends up with the `<include>` item from `main.xml` with `@file=foo` to have the path `path/to/foo`, taken from `include_paths.xml`. This would produce the following expected result:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="path/to/foo">foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="path/to/bar">bar</a></li>
</ul>
```

I think my problem is the namespacing (scoping?) in the XPath expression, where I can't distinguish the `@name` and `@file` tags. My guess is that the scope of the `document(...)` function is of the `$include_paths` variable and hence `include_paths.xml` file, but my problem is then how I refer to the `@file` attribute for the XPath expression.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the expected result of your example?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Added expected output for completeness, although a solution has already been posted by Martin Honnen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `current()` in `<a href="#{document($include_paths)/includes/include[@name = current()/@file]/@name}"><xsl:value-of select="@file"/></a>`.